# C++ void argument with variadic template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template in my C++ class:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
ReturnType run(void* context, const Args&... args) {
  /* Do the actual job. */
}
```

For practical reason, I need to specify it for ReturnType void. I need to keep the list of args because they are still useful.

I tried the following but neither works:

```
template <typename... Args>
void run(void* context, const Args&... args) {
  /* Do the actual job. */
}
```

and

```
template <typename ReturnType = void, typename... Args>
void run(void* context, const Args&... args) {
  /* Do the actual job. */
}
```

So.. what is the correct way to specify with the void argument in my example?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called partial function specialization, and this is not allowed in C++. You will need to find a different solution for whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Something like a wrapper?

Comment: may be `std::invoke` can help you

Comment: Yes, like a wrapper. Your function becomes a wrapper that `std::forward`s its parameters to a static method of a template class that uses the same template parameters as the function. Then, you can partially-specialize the template class's parameters with the appropriate static method in the specialization. It's a fairly common technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++17, this is simple: use `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
ReturnType run(void* context, const Args&... args) {
    if constexpr (std::is_void_v<ReturnType>) {
        /* void case */
    } else {
        /* non-void case */
    }
}
```

Before C++17, the best way to do this is with tag dispatching. Create a new class template that just encodes the type, so that you can pass it as an argument:

```
template <typename T> struct tag { };

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
ReturnType run_impl(tag<ReturnType>, void* context, const Args&... args) {
    /* non-void case */
}

template <typename... Args>
void run_impl(tag<void>, void* context, const Args&... args) {
    /* void case */
}

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
ReturnType run(void* context, const Args&... args) {
    return run_impl(tag<ReturnType>{}, context, args...);
}
```